# Copy directory to multiple directories - I/O performance matters

Tags: python, multithreading, console

I am working on below python copy utility that should work on windows & linux,
But I am looking for a more efficient approach that could optimize my I/O correction, as my target location is network dependent as well...
I have computed the utility execution time factor in the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""
Pythonic implementation of multi-target copy (Parallel Copy).    
"""

import Queue
import threading
import time
import os, os.path
import sys
import shutil, hashlib

exitFlag = 0

class myThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, queue, idFlag):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.queue = queue
        self.idFlag = idFlag

    def run(self):
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Starting %s" % self.name
        process_data(self.name, self.queue, self.idFlag)
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Ending %s" % self.name

def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    sha512_hash = hashlib.sha512()
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    try:
        with open(src_filepath, "r") as sf:
            statinfo = os.stat(src_filepath)
            block_size = 100 * (2 ** 20)  # Magic number: 100 * 1MB blocks
            nb_blocks = (statinfo.st_size / block_size) + 1
            cnt_blocks = 0

            l = len(src_filepath.split('\\'))
            target_file_path = os.path.join(target_filename, src_filepath.split('\\')[l - 1])

            while True:
                block = sf.read(block_size)
                sha512_hash.update(block)   # Todo a blockwise copy
                if not block: break
                cnt_blocks = cnt_blocks + 1
                with open(target_filename, "a") as tf:
                    tf.write(block)
                tf.close()

            print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
            sf.close()
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)

def delete_folder(target_path):
    """
    Deletes a folder, if it already exists
    @param target_path: Relative path of the directory to delete
    """
    if (os.path.exists(target_path) or os.path.isdir(target_path)):
        print "Directory %s already exists.. deleting..." % target_path
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(target_path)
        except OSError:
            os.remove(target_path)

def process_data(threadName, queue, idFlag):
    while not exitFlag:
        if not workQueue.empty():
            (sfile, dfile) = queue.get()
            copy_files_concurrantly(sfile, dfile, idFlag)
        time.sleep(0.5)

def queue_mt(argv):
    """
    Implementation to do multi-target copy (recursive) of directories
    @param argv: Arguments passed at command-line 
    """
    desc = "Recursively copies the files to destination directories."
    syntax = "\nUsage:\n c4.py cp -L -R <src-dir> <target-dir>\n c4.py cp -L -R <src-dir> -t <target-dir1> <target-dir2>..."
    options = "\n\n    cp\t\t\tCopy operation to perform.\n    -L\t\t\tDisplay running logs.(Optional)\n    -R\t\t\tRecursively copy source files to target.\n    <src-dir>\t\tSpecify source directory to copy.\n    <target-dir>\tSpecify target directory to copy."
    win = "\n\n  Windows: c4.py cp -R d:\src-dir\*.* e:\dst-dir  (OR)  c4.py cp -R d:\src-dir\*.* -t d:\dst-dir1 e:\dst-dir2"
    linux = "\n  Linux: c4.py cp -R /src-dir/*.* /dst-dir  (OR)  c4.py cp -R /src-dir/*.* -t /dst-dir1 /dst-dir2"

    cmd_usage = desc + syntax + options + win + linux

    # Displays the command-usage incase of incorrect arguments specified 
    if len(argv) < 4:
        print cmd_usage
        sys.exit(2)

    global threadID, workQueue, debugFlag
    threads, threadList, threadID, debugFlag, cnt = [], [], 1, False, 0
    stime = time.time()

    # Perform single source to single target directory copy
    if ((len(argv) == 4) and (("-R" in argv[1]) or ("-r" in argv[1]))) or ((len(argv) == 5) and (("-R" in argv[2]) or ("-r" in argv[2]))):
        if (len(argv) == 4):
            src_path, dest_path = argv[2], argv[3]
        if (len(argv) == 5) and ("-L" in argv[1]):
            debugFlag = True
            src_path, dest_path = argv[3], argv[4]
        if src_path.endswith('/*') or src_path.endswith('\*'):
            src_path = src_path[:-2]
        if src_path.endswith('/*.*') or src_path.endswith('\*.*'):
            src_path = src_path[:-4]

        # Computing the file-count recursively traversing the directory
        # Excludes the count of number of directories
        fcnt = sum([len(f) for r, d, f in os.walk(src_path)])
        print "File)s) count in source directory: %d" % fcnt
        cnt = fcnt * 1
        workQueue = Queue.Queue(cnt)

        # Fill the Queue
        for root, subfolder, filenames in os.walk(src_path):
            newDir = os.path.join(dest_path, root[1 + len(src_path):])
            if not os.path.exists(newDir):
                os.makedirs(newDir)
            else:
                delete_folder(newDir)
            for filename in filenames:
                sfpath = str(os.path.join(root, filename))
                dfpath = str(os.path.join(newDir, filename))
                workQueue.put((sfpath, dfpath))
                if debugFlag:
                    print "***** Added to Q... %s | %s" % (sfpath, dfpath)

    elif ((len(argv) > 4) and (("-t" in argv[3]) or ("-t" in argv[4]))):
        if ("-L" in argv[1]):
            debugFlag = True
            src_path, st = argv[3], 5
        else:
            src_path, st = argv[2], 4
        if src_path.endswith('/*') or src_path.endswith('\*'):
            src_path = src_path[:-2]
        if src_path.endswith('/*.*') or src_path.endswith('\*.*'):
            src_path = src_path[:-4]

        # Computing the file-count recursively traversing the directory
        # Excludes the count of number of directories
        fcnt = sum([len(f) for r, d, f in os.walk(src_path)])
        if ("-L" in argv[1]):
            dst = (len(argv) - 5)
        else:
            dst = (len(argv) - 4)
        print "File(s) count in source directory:%d | Destination directories count:%s" % (fcnt, dst)
        cnt = fcnt * dst
        workQueue = Queue.Queue(cnt)

        # Fill the Queue
        for root, subfolder, filenames in os.walk(src_path):
            for i in range(st, (len(argv))):
                dest_path = argv[i]
                newDir = os.path.join(dest_path, root[1 + len(src_path):])
                if not os.path.exists(newDir):
                    os.makedirs(newDir)
                else:
                    delete_folder(newDir)
                for filename in filenames:
                    sfpath = str(os.path.join(root, filename))
                    dfpath = str(os.path.join(newDir, filename))
                    workQueue.put((sfpath, dfpath))
                    if debugFlag:
                        print "***** Added to Q... %s | %s" % (sfpath, dfpath)

    print "\nGenerating c4id's for source directory files only...\n"
    # Create new threads
    max_threads = 100
    if cnt > max_threads:
        cnt = max_threads
    for i in range(1, cnt+1):
        s = 'Thread'+str(i)
        threadList.append(s)
    if debugFlag:
        print "***** ThreadsList: %s" % str(threadList)
    for tName in threadList:
        thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue, idFlag=True)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        threadID += 1

    # Wait for queue to empty
    while not workQueue.empty():
        pass

    # Notify threads its time to exit
    global exitFlag
    exitFlag = 1

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    if debugFlag:
        print "\nUtility Exec time: %s sec" %(time.time() - stime)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue_mt(sys.argv[1:])
```

Answer (score 2):

Let me begin with `copy_files_concurrantly`.

The `sha512_hash` variable is not used, except for being updated. It can go. The same goes for `nb_blocks`, `cnt_blocks`, `stat_info`, `target_file_path`, `l`.

```
def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    try:
        with open(src_filepath, "r") as sf:
            block_size = 100 * (2 ** 20)  # Magic number: 100 * 1MB blocks

            while True:
                block = sf.read(block_size)
                if not block: break
                with open(target_filename, "a") as tf:
                    tf.write(block)
                tf.close()

            print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
            sf.close()
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)
```

This way, the code is just a bit more readable, because you're left with only the functional part of the code.

Another thing that's worrisome is using `with` blocks and manually closing the file. A `with` block closes the file when the code leaves the `with` block. Let's get rid of the explicit `close`.

```
def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    try:
        with open(src_filepath, "r") as sf:
            block_size = 100 * (2 ** 20)  # Magic number: 100 * 1MB blocks

            while True:
                block = sf.read(block_size)
                if not block: break
                with open(target_filename, "a") as tf:
                    tf.write(block)

            print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)
```

Another thing to note is that the target_file is getting opened and closed all the time. We can do better!

```
def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    try:
        with open(src_filepath, "r") as sf, open(target_filename, "a") as tf:
            block_size = 100 * (2 ** 20)  # Magic number: 100 * 1MB blocks

            while True:
                block = sf.read(block_size)
                if not block: break
                tf.write(block)

            print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)
```

One last improvement: use `partial` and `iter`:

```
while True:
    block = sf.read(block_size)
    if not block:
        break
    ...
```

can be written as

```
from functools import partial

for block in iter(partial(sf.read, block_size), ''):
     ...
```

Leaving us with

```
def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    try:
        with open(src_filepath, "r") as sf, open(target_filename, "a") as tf:
            block_size = 100 * (2 ** 20)  # Magic number: 100 * 1MB blocks

            for block in iter(partial(sf.read, block_size), ''):
                tf.write(block)

            print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)
```

Another (very!!!) import suggestion would be to move the `print` statement up a bit higher.

```
from functools import partial

def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
    try:
        with open(src_filepath, "r") as sf, open(target_filename, "a") as tf:
            block_size = 100 * (2 ** 20)  # Magic number: 100 * 1MB blocks

            for block in iter(partial(sf.read, block_size), ''):
                tf.write(block)
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)
```

Especially if the file is large, and needs to be transfered over the network, it's good to know what the file is working on.

Now, I assume the `"a"` is now a bug, as the file no longer gets truncated. Assuming we can replace it with `"w"` instead, we could write:

```
import shutil

def copy_files_concurrantly(src_filename, target_filename, idFlag):
    """
    """
    src_filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), src_filename)
    print "\nCopying %s (to) %s" % (src_filepath, target_filename)
    try:
        shutil.copy(src_filepath, target_filename)
    except IOError:
        print "Error: cant find or read '%s' file" % (src_filename)
```

And be done with it.

There's probably a lot that can be cleaned up further in the rest of the code, but I just wanted to give a short overview of how to fix the `copy_files_concurrantly`.

Comment: While you're at it, it should be spelled `_concurrently` too.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't quite understand is: Why is `process_data` outside of your `myThread` class? I mean, you give it the whole set of attributes as parameters; and there is only one call to it: inside of the `run` method.

If you did that to use the `global exitFlag` in `queue_mt`, well, it a bad idea. Globals are considered bad practice and there exist way better alternatives to synchronize informations between threads. You can use [`event`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#event-objects) for instance:

```
def queue_mt(argv):

    ...

    # Create new threads
    cnt = min(100, cnt) ## No need to do a compare-and-set explicitly here
    threadList = ['Thread{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, cnt+1)] ## List comprehension is better than loop + append
    if debugFlag:
        print "***** ThreadsList:", threadList

    exit = threading.Event()
    for threadID, tName in enumerate(threadList): ## Let python do the indexing for you
        thread = myThread(threadID, tName, workQueue, exit, idFlag=True)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)

    # Wait for queue to empty
    while not workQueue.empty():
        pass

    # Notify threads its time to exit
    exit.set()

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    if debugFlag:
        print "\nUtility Exec time: %s sec" %(time.time() - stime)
```

Small tips in here before going on:

- `cnt = max_thread if cnt > max_thread else cnt` is clearer (to me) than what you wrote. `cnt = min(cnt, max_thread)` is better. You may want to define `MAX_THREAD = 100` as a constant at the top of your file, though.
- `threadList = []` + loop + `threadList.append(...)` is bad practice: use a list comprehension instead.
- string concatenation is a poor way of building strings, use `format` you'll have more control over the formatting.
- you almost never need to maintain an explicit index in Python. Use `enumerate` while iterating over a collection if you need one.

So we added an `Event` as the fourth parameter of `myThread` let's handle that. And in the meantime, give a meaningful name to that class:

```
class ThreadedFileCopy(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, queue, event, idFlag):
        supe(ThreadedFileCopy, self).__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.queue = queue
        self.stop = event
        self.idFlag = idFlag

    def run(self):
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Starting %s" % self.name
        while not self.stop.is_set():
            if not workQueue.empty():
                (sfile, dfile) = self.queue.get()
                copy_files_concurrantly(sfile, dfile, self.idFlag)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Ending %s" % self.name
```

This got me thinking… Where does this global `workQueue` come from? Oh there is a `global workQueue` in `queue_mt`. And you build your thread passing `workQueue` as the third parameter. So basically, `workQueue` is `self.queue`; why not use that in the first place?

Also, looking at its usage, you populate the queue before creating the threads. They are merely consumers and should stop as soon as the queue is empty, but you do not need any synchronization mechanisms for that you can know when the queue is empty directly in the thread: use [`get_nowait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get_nowait) and handle the exception to terminate gracefully:

```
class ThreadedFileCopy(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, queue, idFlag):
        supe(ThreadedFileCopy, self).__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.queue = queue
        self.idFlag = idFlag

    def run(self):
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Starting %s" % self.name
        try:
            while True:
                (sfile, dfile) = self.queue.get_nowait()
                copy_files_concurrantly(sfile, dfile, self.idFlag)
        except queue.Empty:
            # Continue gracefully when every file has been handled
            pass
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Ending %s" % self.name
```

So, it turns out we didn't need that `Event` after all. I also removed the `time.sleep(0.5)`, I don't understand why you put that here in the first place if performances matters.

---

Now let's get back to `queue_mt` for the usage. Since each thread now stops itself when the queue is empty, there is no need to monitor that in this function. We can also improve the way threads are created and reduce the amount of useless data stored.

```
MAX_THREADS = 100

def queue_mt(argv):

    ...

    # Create new threads
    threadList = [
        ThreadedFileCopy(i, 'Thread{}'.format(i+1), workQueue, True)
        for i in range(min(MAX_THREADS, cnt))
    ]

    if debugFlag:
        print "***** ThreadsList:", threadList

    for thread in threadList:
        thread.start()

    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for thread in threadList:
        thread.join()

    if debugFlag:
        print "\nUtility Exec time: %s sec" %(time.time() - stime)
```

This way you don't need to store both the names **and** the threads since the latter contains the former. It also lets you build the list of threads faster. Oh, and while I’m at it, stop declaring your variable way earlier than where you will need them (such as `threads, threadList, threadID, debugFlag, cnt = [], [], 1, False, 0`). Python is a dynamic language, if you happen to need a variable at some point, just perform an assignment at this point.

However, there is one problem now, the call to `print "***** ThreadsList:", threadList` gives an unhelpfull reprensation of the threads in the list. When building the string representation of the list, Python had no difficulties to convert a list of strings to a single string. But now it has to convert a list of threads to a string and it doesn't really know oh to convert a thread to a string. Let's help it a little by adding the `__repr__` method to our thread object:

```
class ThreadedFileCopy(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, queue, idFlag):
        supe(ThreadedFileCopy, self).__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.queue = queue
        self.idFlag = idFlag

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def run(self):
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Starting %s" % self.name
        try:
            while True:
                (sfile, dfile) = self.queue.get_nowait()
                copy_files_concurrantly(sfile, dfile, self.idFlag)
        except queue.Empty:
            # Continue gracefully when every file has been handled
            pass
        if debugFlag:
            print "**** Ending %s" % self.name
```

And there it is, same output than previously.

---

One last note, we removed the need for `global workQueue`, we removed the need for `threadID` at all, try to avoid using globals for `debugFlag` too. You can pass it as a parameter for the thread and call it a day.

I could also have told you about how managing command-line parsing and performing the logic in the same function is pretty bad, you should parse the command line beforehand and then call the function performing the logic with the right set of parameters. I could also have told you about [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) or [`getopt`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html#module-getopt) to generate usage message and parse command line options… but I’ll let that to someone else.